# Rename All Files in a Folder ( Swapping the words/numbers separated by '_' )

Tags: java, windows, file, rename

I have a folder in "Windows 10" Operating System with files named as;

```
afilename_1
bfilename_3
cfilename_2
```

This is how it appears. But I need it to make it sorted according to numbers appended after the underscore. I want the words before underscore, as well as they, depict file description.

**Hint**:  Swapping the words/numbers separated by '_'.

Output expected:

```
1_afilename
2_cfilename
3_bfilename
```

Any idea apart from manual renaming?

**P.S.** The folder consists of 100's of files.
A Solution in Java programming language is appreciable but not mandatory.

**Update (10.01.2017)** : Here is the sample Java code figured out to get all file names as output.

```
File folder = new File("/xxx/ss/folder/"); 
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
for (File file : listOfFiles) 
{ if (file.isFile()) 
{ System.out.println(file.getName()); 
} }
```

Now, thinking how to get each filename at once and swapping done in a loop.
Any thoughts?

**Solution**: Windows Powershell code worked.

If input: file names are as follows

```
xxx_afilename_1
xxx_bfilename_3
xxx_cfilename_2
```

then the following code helps in getting similar output as stated above.

```
ls | %{ ren $_ ($_.name -replace '.*?-(.*?)-(.*?)(\..*)','$2_$1$3') }
```

Comment: Well you can use regex to separate the file names and format it as per your need.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, perhaps in java as you have added that tag.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ here is the sample Java code figured out to get all file names as output. 
`File folder = new File("/Users/you/folder/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}`
Now, thinking how get each filename at once and swapping done in a loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41551368/edit) and add it in the question body, not in the comment.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Thank you for the suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Powershell

`ls | %{ ren $_ ($_.name -replace '(.+)_(.+)','$2_$1') }`

**Update for keeping extension**

`ls | %{ ren $_ ($_.name -replace '(.+)_(.+)(\..+)','$2_$1$3') }`

Comment: It's simple and almost worked for my question. Let's say the files are text files. Output was as follows;
`1.txt_afilename  
2.txt_cfilename  
3.txt_bfilename`  
Neither that was my desired output nor the files are readable because of extension conflict. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Updated answer to keep file extension.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of.

It is a fairly simple program to write in C/C++/C# or Python or what-have-you. Depending on your expertise it may take as long to write and debug the program as to do the job by hand, but much more fun.

A good programmers text editor can take a list of files such as from a directory listing and generate a .bat file with the rename commands in. Such things as macros and regular-expression search-and-replace makes the job fairly painless. (I always recommend jEdit -- free, multiplatform and powerful.)

Comment: Interesting! could you, please link me any learning material so that it helps me to give a try. Thank you for the response. (: